# User's homepage depending on their organic group

Tags: 7, organic-groups

Is there a way to set the homepage of a user depending on their organic group. So when a user clicks the site logo, they will be redirected to something like /test-page/%group. When I created a panel page it specified that I could not use % which would have been perfect.

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Do you use D7 or D6 ? Do you use Tokens module ?

Comment: Using D7 and yes I'm using the token module.

Comment: Can your user be assigned to more then one organic group ?

Comment: no only to one group.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module ([Frontpage](http://drupal.org/project/frontpage)) that allows to set a different front page for anonymous users, and authenticated users.

The module allows third-party modules to alter the page to which the users are instead redirected, or to alter the structure array used to render the page.

As alternative, you can create a custom module that, using code similar to the one used by Frontpage, redirect users to a specific page, basing on specific criteria.

The module should implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and associate a menu callback to, for example, http://example.com/frontpage; the page callback of that menu item should simply verify a condition is verified, and then redirect the users to a specific URL.

The code skeleton could be something similar to the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['frontpage'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_frontpage_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_frontpage_view() {
  // These variables can be useful to redirect the users
  // to specific pages, basing on the language currently set for
  // the content, or on the fact the user is logged in.
  $langcode = $GLOBALS['language_content']->language;
  $logged_in = user_is_logged_in();
  $usergroups = og_get_groups_by_user($user);
  $group = og_load($gid);
  $groupnode = $group->etid;
  $redirectpath = 'node/'.$groupnode->nid;
  drupal_goto($redirectpath);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea how to do this with contrib modules only:

1. Use *Views* and *[Views Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_field)* modules to show 
    the OG group as a view inside the frontpage view in step 2
2. Create the frontpage View that will show the OG group of the current user
   Use relationship: Content: Author to filter the user group only
   Use view field to show OG group fields inside the main view 
   Limit the main view to 1 record only
3. Use System: Site information: (admin/config/system/site-information)
   to replace frontpage with the view created in step 2

   - Use field: *Default front page* to redirect to your new frontpage view

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I will need to take in some values of that group node and use them to manipulate the css. 

For example the group type node has  a hexadecimal colour field for html colours which will be used in the css in a custom content pane inside a panel page.

Comment: The Views module, and the Views Field module are not custom modules; custom modules are modules created for a specific group of sites, such as the Drupal customization module, used for drupal.org sites.

Comment: yes sure I meant contrib modules of course...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used rules links because I wanted it to redirect the user to a panel page that ends with %node. Then I used visibility rules on the rules link for it to show depending on the current user logged in's role. Then I create a view with one record which displays that rules link and then placed it in a block.

So Depending on the users role, that "Home" link will show. When clicked, that user will be redirected to their group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OG 7.2 you can try out the [OG homepage module](http://drupal.org/project/og_homepage). The module basically does what @mohit_rocks outlined.

I made this module a while back and just recently published it on Drupal.

Answer (score -1):

There is programmatical way to do this and even more :) Drupal 7, actual code called from page.tpl.php

```
    //get unique user id
    $user_id = $user -> uid;
    //get id-s of groups where user is a member, from og_membership drupal table
    $og_check = db_select('og_membership', 'n')
            ->fields('n')
            ->condition('etid', $user_id, '=')
            ->execute()
            ->fetchCol($index = 4);

  //if user is multiple group member, use first index [0], 1 is GID
 // (group id, it is defined in OG table in drupal database
    if ($og_check[0]==1) {
    $logo_link = 'http://your-site.com/whatever-start-page-for-group';
    } else {
     $logo_link =  'http://your-site.com/normal-start-page'; 
    }
```

and then print $logo_link inside a href that surrounds logo...
it is pretty specific case, but i need to do this way because targeted group page has nothing to do with actual group page of type group... hope it helps someone